# Flask and SQLAlchemy Questions

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently using Flask and SQLAlchemy to create a web application.

However, I am in the process of creating a User model with passwords and usernames. Do I need to find my own libraries to salt and hash the passwords or does SQLAlchemy or Flask provide this in some way?

Also, what is the most popularly used with Flask and SQLAlchemy for database migrations?

Lets assume that I change my model. How do I drop the old schema and tell SQLAlchemy to use the newer one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are libraries out there that should handle this for you. How much work they do is up to you. Some, like [bcrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/py-bcrypt/) or [passlib](http://pythonhosted.org/passlib/), will just give you the algorithms needed to generate the password hash. Others, like [Flask-Security](https://flask-security.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), go one step more than allow you to use mixins to handle even more.

As for database migrations, check out [alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). It's a migrations utility built by the lead maintainer of SQLAlchemy.

You have another question in there about a "particular way that Flask developers prefer to drop the schema". I'm not sure what this means, but I would imagine that if you went into a bit more detail, you could probably ask it as a separate question. Just keep in mind that any question that asks why something is preferred should be asked cautiously: preferences are subjective, and therefore, asking questions on why something is preferred would also likely be subjective.